# Formulae booklet template

Tags: formatting, templates

For my classes i am allowed to have a math formulae booklet prepared by myself although the maximum size is two a4 pages. I want to make it as legible and organized as possible thus i want to use latex for this purpose hence i am looking for a good template for this type of things (if any exist). If not any ideas how to squeeze as much formulae as possible on two pages would be appreciated.

Comment: You may check the LaTeX RefCard project, https://sourceforge.net/projects/latex-reference-card-creator/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did the same thing when I went to Uni but I used plain TeX.

In places I would use tables, elsewhere I would use a combination of `\hbox`s and `\vbox`s to arrange them in a suitable way. Another important thing is to minimize spaces that happen automatically, like `\baselineskip`, matrices and `\left.`. Use negative *glue* or `\keen` if for example you want to overlap 2 boxes that have white areas. An example of such boxes are two rows, one with `\cases` and one above or below with contents shorter than what's before `\cases`. Or you cound have a formula that starts with an integral symbol, and then you indent the next row so they can be closer together.

You can change the `\fam` fonts to smaller ones so that typeset formulae will be smaller.

When redefining fonts, rather than `cmr7` or even `cmr5` used `cmr10 at 7pt` ot `cmr10 at 5pt` and so on because smaller sizes are relatively wider. The TeXbook demonstrates it by displaying a sentence written with `cmr5 at 10pt` alongside `cmr10`.

If you need bold, use `cmb10` rather than `cmbx10`, it's narrower. (By default, `\rm` refers to fonts `cmr*` and `\bf` refers to `cmbx*`.)

That's what I could think of so far.